# SQL removing duplicate rows but keeping one

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a large dataset which contains duplicate rows with  different IDs. However there are also 'duplicate rows' within the same ID. To consider something as duplicate I only look at the Name, Age, and Length variables. There are other variables such as 'time', which can be or not be identical within the same ID or within another ID.

My goal is to delete the duplicate rows with a different ID, but keep the duplicate rows with the same ID. I have tried several things mentioned on here, but most either delete too much or too little.

In the example data I added a 'time' variable with does not have to be identical to the other record within the same ID, but does not influence the decision whether to delete the row or not.

Example starting data :

| ID | Name | Age | Length | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 25 | 185 | 12:05 |
| 1 | John | 25 | 185 | 11:00 |
| 2 | Boris | 30 | 172 | 13:00 |
| 2 | John | 25 | 185 | 17:00 |
| 2 | Chris | 17 | 190 | 14:30 |
| 2 | Boris | 30 | 172 | 16:30 |
| 3 | John | 25 | 185 | 19:20 |
| 3 | Boris | 30 | 172 | 20:05 |
| 4 | John | 25 | 185 | 12:05 |

Example final data :

| ID | Name | Age | Length | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 25 | 185 | 12:05 |
| 1 | John | 25 | 185 | 11:00 |
| 2 | Boris | 30 | 172 | 13:00 |
| 2 | Boris | 30 | 172 | 16:30 |
| 2 | Chris | 17 | 190 | 14:30 |

So basically I would like to delete 'duplicate' rows with a different ID, but keep duplicate rows within the same ID.

I have looked at similar problems on here and tried solutions such as;

```
with rownums as 
(select *, 
 row_number() over(partition by name,age,length
 order by name,age,length) as rnum
 from TABLE)
delete r
from rownums r
where rnum > 1
```

However this does not take the ID into account and would also delete rows 2,6, and 9 in the example data.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of data (text, integer) is your ID column? You could get the minimum for the set of columns

Comment: why not order by time, so that you would get deterministic results

Answer (score 0):

Please find the indicative answer in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-oeK75RR).

The code includes an inner join between your initial table and a query table. Essentially, the `row_number()` is used for ordering based on the characteristics (name , age, length). After that, a table with the first occurrence is created with the `WHERE` clause. The `inner join` is used with the created table to query your initial table.

```
SELECT T.*
FROM your_table AS T
INNER JOIN (SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, T1.Age, T1.Length
  FROM (SELECT *, 
        row_number() over(partition by Name, Age, Length order by Name, Age, Length) as rnum 
        FROM your_table)T1
  WHERE T1.rnum = 1)T2
ON T.ID = T2.ID AND T.Name = T2.Name AND T.Age = T2.Age AND T.Length = T2.Length
```